# Is this a reasonable start to my string quartet?

Tags: composition, string-instruments, ensemble

[image]

This is what I have of my string quartet so far. I am using Musescore for composing this, so I put in 100 measures because I didn't know how long the first movement of the string quartet would be. If there are no dynamics in the piece, Musescore defaults to playing it mezzo-forte. I exported it as an image and then added the arrows and text to it.

I don't know if I have the cello going too fast with the Alberti bass in the tutti and the eighth notes in the solo. I have my Allegro at 120 BPM. I have been binge-listening to Mozart's string quartets and you can probably see that I am doing a Neo-Mozart, if you will, with this string quartet.

**But is what I have a reasonable start to a string quartet? And importantly, is the cello going too fast there with the Alberti bass and the eighths?**

Answer (score 1):

You're doubling the 3rd of both the tonic and dominant chords a lot.  Actually, the whole harmonic scheme is a bit suspect.  I suggest you consolidate the broken chords into longer notes, so it looks more like a hymn tune, and see if you really like how it sounds.  Particularly around bar 4.

(Actually, just set the tempo slow, maybe q=40, and PLAY bar 4.  Is that really what was in your 'inner ear?')

What does 'Tutti' and 'solo' mean in relation to the cello part of a string quartet?

You don't have to prepare the 'empty manuscript paper' in MuseScore.  It will expand as you enter notes.

Cello can manage 16th note broken chords at q=120.

Comment: What I mean by the Tutti and solo is that the second group of 5 bars, I planned to have as a cello solo and then a transition back to a full Tutti.